# jquery min.js and woocommerce plugin conflicts

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have used various plugin and woocommerce theme in my wordpress. When I am using some Jquery code in it.then getting some conflicts on that page and my plugins stopped working..why? I want to use that jquery code on my site.Please help me.

Comment: You could check the console in chrome developer tools or firebug to see exactly whats going on: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your plugins are running in **[noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)** mode. If they are not, you can try adding **`jQuery.noConflict();`** to the script. You can also test if it is a theme issue by putting your theme to the default TwentyTwelve or TwentyEleven and enabling the plugin. In case of a theme conflict, you would want to contact the developer. Sometimes themes are not developed with compatibility in mind and are prone to plugin conflicts.

Some questions I would ask if you still were having trouble: What theme are you using and where did you get it? What plugin are you trying to enable? Which versions of the aforementioned are you working on as well as your Wordpress version?